# 'G_vmlCanvasManager' is undefined

Tags: javascript, excanvas, highcharts

I am using the highcharts charting library,

i am including excanvas if the browser is ie using

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.compiled.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

yet i still get 
'G_vmlCanvasManager' is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it a typo?

yours is

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.compiled.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

should it be?

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xcanvas.compiled.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I also get this error. It was a I was referencing 'G_vmlCanvasManager' in my javascript instead of 'window.G_vmlCanvasManager'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).